Can I distribute iOS apps with .NET MAUI using Visual Studio for Windows after August 31, 2024?
I am seeking clarification regarding the ability to distribute iOS apps using .NET MAUI after August 31, 2024, given that Visual Studio for Mac will no longer be available. Specifically, I want to know if it is still possible to distribute iOS apps using Visual Studio for Windows.
Here are my questions:
If I use Visual Studio for Windows (on a Windows machine), can I still distribute iOS apps with .NET MAUI?
Is it necessary to have a Mac with Xcode installed and connected to the same Wi-Fi network remotely to build and distribute iOS apps?
After August 31, 2024, will there be any restrictions or changes that prevent me from distributing iOS apps using Visual Studio for Windows with .NET MAUI?
Thank you for your assistance.
I have been researching the upcoming changes to Visual Studio for Mac and how they might impact my ability to distribute iOS apps using .NET MAUI. I read the official announcements and looked through the documentation, but I couldn't find a clear answer regarding the specific scenario of using Visual Studio for Windows to distribute iOS apps after August 31, 2024.


If I use Visual Studio for Windows (on a Windows machine), can I still
distribute iOS apps with .NET MAUI? Is it necessary to have a Mac with
Xcode installed and connected to the same Wi-Fi network remotely to
build and distribute iOS apps?

Yes, you can and it's necessary to have a Mac with Xcode and Pair to Mac to build and distribute iOS apps as you said. And there are several alternative solutions to using Visual Studio for Mac which will no longer be supported or maintained after August 31, 2024, see Alternative options for developing on the Mac
Useful links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/
